# Celery communication with rabbitmq is unstable

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to run my task with celery.

I am getting following error. i am able to run tasks and get response. But, its not stable, and the response time changes based this connection error.

I am using the sample code from documentation.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('jira2case', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

[2020-05-12 15:15:57,833: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

[2020-05-12 15:16:03,851: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)

[2020-05-12 15:16:10,210: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2020-05-12 15:16:14,221: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

[2020-05-12 15:16:20,235: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)

Comment: Please post minimal code that produces it.

Comment: I am using the sample code from the documentation.


from celery import Celery
app = Celery('jira2case', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')



@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

Comment: Did you try to connect to that amqp URL using regular RabbitMQ client?

Comment: @DejanLekic I tried with pika as per the rabbitmq tutorial. It works without any error.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

Comment: With the same URL, on the same machine?